# New iCal Meeting requests opening old calendar items

Tags: ical, calendar

Ever since upgrading to Mountain Lion (10.8.2), I'm having an issue with my Calendar.  It seems like all of the new meeting invites I receive are incorrectly associating with old meetings (2009 and 2010) on my calendar.  I'll receive an invite for a new meeting.  I'll click on the attached .ics file, which will take me to an existing meeting from several years ago instead of creating a new meeting on my calendar.

Is anyone else having this problem?  More importantly, does anyone know how to fix this?

Many thanks.